# Insert string with special characters into bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

anybody can help me, how I can write to bat file this string

```
"cmd /c echo open blabla blabla >> 123.txt"
```

without "

Comment: Use `^>^>` instead of `>>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [escape](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) each `>` with a `^`.

```
echo cmd /c echo open blabla blabla ^>^> 123.txt >> C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\123.txt
```